# Is there a better way to do an "unravel" function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was faced with the problem of executing `n` number of concurrent events that all return iterators to the results they aquired. However, there was an optional `limit` parameter that says, basically, to consolidate all the iterators and return up-to `limit` results.

So, for example: I execute 2,000 url requests on 8 threads but just want the first 100 results, but not all 100 from the same potential thread.

Thus, `unravel`:

```
import itertools

def unravel(*iterables, with_limit = None):
    make_iter = {a:iter(i) for a,i in enumerate(iterables)}

    if not isinstance(with_limit, int):
        with_limit = -1

    resize = False

    while True:
        for iid, take_from in make_iter.items():
            if with_limit == 0:
                raise StopIteration

            try:
                yield next(take_from)
            except StopIteration:
                resize = iid
            else: 
                with_limit -= 1

        if resize:
            resize = False

            if len(make_iter.keys()) > 1:
                make_iter.pop(resize)

            else: raise StopIteration
```

Usage:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [6,7,8,9,10]
>>> c = [1,3,5,7]
>>> d = [2,4,6,8]
>>> 
>>> print([e for e in unravel(c, d)])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> print([e for e in unravel(c, d, with_limit = 3)])
[1, 2, 3]
>>> print([e for e in unravel(a, b, with_limit = 6)])
[1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8]
>>> print([e for e in unravel(a, b, with_limit = 100)])
[1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10]
```

Does something like this already exist, or is this a decent implementation?

Thanks

***EDIT, WORKING FIX***

Inspired by @abernert 's suggestion, this is what I went with. Thanks everybody!

```
def unravel(*iterables, limit = None):
    yield from itertools.islice(
            filter(None,
                itertools.chain.from_iterable(
                    itertools.zip_longest(
                        *iterables
                    )
                ) 
            ), limit)



>>> a = [x for x in range(10)]
>>> b = [x for x in range(5)]
>>> c = [x for x in range(0, 20, 2)]
>>> d = [x for x in range(1, 30, 2)]
>>> 
>>> print(list(unravel(a, b)))
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> print(list(unravel(a, b, limit = 3)))
[1, 1, 2]
>>> print(list(unravel(a, b, c, d, limit = 20)))
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 5, 3, 3, 6, 7, 4, 4, 8, 9, 5, 10, 11]
```

Comment: Just as a comment, if you know 'with_limit' in advance, you may not need to have the lists evaluated and stored completely. Use 'yield' statement in your evaluater function with parameter of 'with_limit', and break out to return when hitting limit.

Comment: Aside: `[e for e in something_iterable]` can be written `list(something_iterable)` instead.

Comment: Also, it might be much better to just use a `multiprocessing.imap`, a `concurrent.futures.map`, etc. instead of trying to do this manually in the first place…

Comment: Yeah, it's much more productive to delete the working version I made from information I recieved by asking the question. @jonrsharpe

Comment: @blakev you can still see it in the edit history if you like. Bear in mind that you can answer your own question if you think the other answers are insufficient (in which case, why is one accepted?)

Comment: @jonrsharpe nobody reads the edit history. Thanks for making my 7 month old 60 view post worthless! Cheers.

Comment: Worthless? It is a decent question with multiple upvotes answers, which is far from worthless. That still doesn't mean that you should put answers in the question; again, you can add your own answer if you want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing here is almost just `zip`.

You want a flat iterable, rather than an iterable of sub-iterables, but `chain` fixes that.

And you want to take only the first N values, but `islice` fixes that.

So, if the lengths are all equal:

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b)))
[1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10]
>>> list(islice(chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b)), 7))
[1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4]
```

But if the lengths aren't equal, that will stop as soon as the first iterable finishes, which you don't want. And the only alternative in the stdlib is `zip_longest`, which fills in missing values with `None`.

You can pretty easily write a `zip_longest_skipping` (which is effectively the `round_robin` in Peter's answer), but you can also just `zip_longest` and filter out the results:

```
>>> list(filter(None, chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(a, b, c, d))))
[1, 6, 1, 2, 2, 7, 3, 4, 3, 8, 5, 6, 4, 9, 7, 8, 5, 10]
```

(Obviously this doesn't work as well if your values are all either strings or `None`, but when they're all positive integers it works fine… to handle the "or `None`" case, do `sentinel=object()`, pass that to `zip_longest`, then filter on `x is not sentinel`.)

Comment: This also works (the output from your test is identical to the roundrobin implementation) and is a bit clearer. I am not sure yet about the performance differences, if any.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: If you have one gigantic list and a bunch of tiny ones, and you do almost no work beyond consuming the iterator, the cost of generating and tossing all those `None` or `sentinel` values can be huge. Practically, it rarely is. I think using `roundrobin` is still better, but it's probably more important to understand how this stuff works, by reading both of our answers, than to get the best code…

Comment: Thanks @abarnert I used a combination of your two suggestions to achieve what I wanted :) much simpler than my original implementation -- and it makes total sense. I wasn't using chain correctly when I first looked into using built-in `itertools` functions.

Comment: @blakev: Yeah, it's confusing that `chain` is the obvious way to flatten an iterable, but if you're thinking in terms of "flatten an iterable" it's actually `chain.from_iterable`, not `chain`, that you want to call, and `chain` seems to work but does nothing…

Answer (score 3):

From the `itertools` example recipes:

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

Use `itertools.islice` to enforce your `with_limit`, eg:

```
print([e for e in itertools.islice(roundrobin(c, d), 3)])

>>> list(roundrobin(a, b, c, d))
[1, 6, 1, 2, 2, 7, 3, 4, 3, 8, 5, 6, 4, 9, 7, 8, 5, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

For what you're actually trying to do, there's probably a much better solution.

> I execute 2,000 url requests on 8 threads but just want the first 100 results, but not all 100 from the same potential thread.

OK, so why are the results in 8 separate iterables? There's no good reason for that. Instead of giving each thread its own queue (or global list and lock, or whatever you're using) and then trying to zip them together, why not have them all share a queue in the first place?

In fact, that's the default way that almost any thread pool is designed (including `multiprocessing.Pool` and `concurrent.futures.Executor` in the stdlib). Look at the main example for [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example):

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

That's almost exactly your use case—spamming a bunch of URL downloads out over 5 different threads and gathering the results as they come in—without your problem even arising.

Of course it's missing `with_limit`, but you can just wrap that `as_completed` iterable in `islice` to handle that, and you're done.

Comment: I am using a ProcessPoolExecutor for this, but thanks :)

Comment: @blakev: OK… then why do you have 8 separate iterators? The easy way to use a `ProcessPoolExecutor` is to just return the results from each task, and iterate the futures (whether by `submit`/`as_completed` or `map`) in the caller. If you had to go out of your way to split the results up, just to weave them back together, why not just not do that?

Comment: The futures return iterators, and not all futures need to finish to get the first `n` results.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a generator and izip_longest to pull one item at a time from multiple iterators

```
from itertools import izip_longest


def  unravel(cap, *iters):

    counter = 0
    for slice in izip_longest(*iters):
        for entry in [s for s in slice if s is not None]:
            yield entry
            counter += 1
            if counter >= cap: break
```